# Setting Up Wifi Stretch Lite (Command line)

Tags: raspbian, raspbian-stretch, pi-zero-w

I am using the following command

> sudo nano /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf

and my file looks like this

```
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1
country=GB

network={
        ssid="your ssid here"
        psk="your psk here"
        key_mgmt=WPA2-PSK
}
```

Obviously with the correct ssid and pass... However, when I run sudo ifconfig or wget it doesn't connect to the internet. Is there something I am missing?

This is a pi zero w

Is there something else missing for it to work?

Comment: `when I run sudo ifconfig or wget it doesn't connect to the internet`. Please add the output of `ifconfig`(no sudo) to your question.

Comment: And please also add the output of `sudo iw wlan0 info` and `sudo iw wlan0 link`.

Comment: What happens if you kill and restart wpa_supplicant?  
    ```/sbin/wpa_supplicant -B -c/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf -iwlan0 -Dnl80211```

Comment: See [How to set up networking/WiFi](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/37921/8697)
As you have provided no diagnostic information no one can help. PS `ifconfig` is deprecated.